# How to get information about security updates for Alpine Linux?

Tags: security, docker, package-management, alpine

I would like to get information that important package updates occured (e.g. connected with security updates) - so that I know, that I need to rebuild my Alpine-based images with apps.

It could be sth similar to Debian's https://www.debian.org/security/ with the list DSA https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/ .

There are some mailing lists for Alpine https://lists.alpinelinux.org/lists/%7Ealpine , but they seem not sufficient for my use case (e.g. https://lists.alpinelinux.org/~alpine/announce has only info about OS releases).

Is there anything like that? Or: Is there any other procedure to keep Alpine-based systems secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matter was discussed these days at alpine/users group [here](https://lists.alpinelinux.org/%7Ealpine/users/%3C2013507513.1487922.1576682692429%40mail.yahoo.com%3E#%3C2060478568.5154258.1577175448132@mail.yahoo.com%3E) So for now the best and acceptable for me option is to use the RSS feed. The RSS feed is with info about closed Security issues.

RSS: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/issues.atom?state=closed&label_name%5B%5D=tag%3Asecurity

List of issues in GitLab: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/issues?state=closed&label_name%5B%5D=tag%3Asecurity

So you can get notified about new SecFixes and decide if you need to rebuild your images. You can use [rss2email](https://pypi.org/project/rss2email/) to be notified via e-mail.

Comment: I think the label name changed, this works for me: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues.atom?state=closed&label_name[]=tag%3Asecurity

Answer (score 1):

Didn't found nothing fancy like Debian's security page, but you might have a look into this: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/log/?h=v3.10.3

The security fixes appear on the log message, might be possible to track it by that.